# Timed out after 30000ms when I try to go next page by clicking login button in automation testing in selenium ide

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

I'm currently testing a website and prepared a test case for the login page and in that test case, my last command (i.e. click) is always passed but the page is not loaded after the click on login button in automation testing, but when i click on login button manually it loads the page and homepage appears.

I tried the same with different commands i.e. clickAndWait/ clickAtAndWait/ waitforPageToLoad but it throws [error] Timed out.

I tried the commands with different timeouts i.e. 30000ms/ 60000ms/ 120000ms but it consistently throws [error] which results to Test case failed.

Please advise. Thank you

Comment: Yes, the page never loads at all during automatic replay and the same happens with Chrome IDE.